# How to execute bat file after some steps in SelenumBase?

Tags: python, captcha, seleniumbase

ive got the program that recognizes captcha.
And i need in SeleniumBase test do the next steps:

1. download captcha png, save it somewhere in system folder
2. run batch file to process downloaded png
3. result is saved in txt, read the result

```
import os
from seleniumbase import BaseCase


class captcha():
    os.system("C:\\captcha\\run_captcha.bat" + " 1.png C:\\captcha\\ 1") 


class LoginTest(BaseCase):
    def test_login(self):
        self.open ("url")
        self.save_element_as_image_file("#CaptchaControl1_CaptchaImage", "1", r"C:\\captcha")
        #os.system("C:\\captcha\\run_captcha.bat" + " 1.png C:\\captcha\\ 1") returns INTERNALERROR if called here
        captcha()
```

but there is the problem:
somehow the result of the run_captcha.bat appears before seleniumbase opens the browser and downloads the image
how to execute batch after downloading the image?

Comment: Rather than trying to solve a captcha, maybe you can bypass it entirely by running seleniumbase in undetected mode with the ``--uc`` option. Example run command: ``pytest --uc``.

Comment: We can develop a bypass, but it will cost the project money, plus for the current framework, one enthusiast has already trained a neural network for our captcha, and now I'm thinking of just taking it for the new framework.

Comment: also, we can't implement jwt, and we cant disable captcha on the test environment, because of critical data

Comment: There are several tests here that use `save_element_as_image_file()`: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_image_saving.py

Comment: @MichaelMintz thank you for link, but nothing fits, there is no actions with file after saving it.

Also just discovered that the result of the run_captcha.bat program appears before opening the browser, performing all the steps of the test and downloading the file, thats why the result is empty